# What is the standard approach to creating DOM Elements from an Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What are some standard approaches to load up a repeating DOM structure from an Ajax JSON object?

This is a plain jQuery application.

Example: I have a complex DOM structure corresponding to a "Question",

```
<div class="list-group">
   <a class="someClass data=toggle="collapse">
       <span class="someSpanClass">**QuestionTopLevel**
       </span>
       <div class="someDivClass">
          <div class="someSubDivClass">
              **QuestionSubElement1**
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="someDivClass">
          <div class="someSubDivClass">
              **QuestionSubElement2**
          </div>
       </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

In this example my dynamic placeholders (marked with `**`) are `QuestionTopLevel, QuestionSubElement1, QuestionSubElement2`.

The Ajax response coming back from the server is of the type

```
"QuestionTopLevel" : { "QuestionSubElement1", "QuestionSubElement2" }
```

I can manually try to insert/remove DOM elements in jQuery using `$('..').insertAfter(..)` but that has some problems:

- Too verbose, there are lots of DOM sub-structures in this "repeater"
- What if the structure changes?

Is there some standard tool or technique to deal with DOM "repeater" structures from an Ajax JSON response?

Comment: Creating HTML from HTML strings with JS is not flexible. Use real dynamic  element creation instead.

Comment: templates / string template literals

Comment: Why not made a generic JSON to HTML object then define your DOM in JSON for example:  {node:"div", attributes:[{class:"someDivClass", ...}]}  Then create a function that takes this json and generates the DOM from it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "real dynamic element creation tool"? Are you referring to a library of some sort?

Comment: No libraries needed, something like SPlatten has described above. Instead of inserting HTML strings, pass the element names, attributes and content in JSON structure, that way you can use a simple recursive loop to create what ever HTML element structures are passed.

Comment: No SPlatten's approach won't work. As I said the DOM structure is nested, in arbitrary ways, not just a 2-layer Node/Attributes map. There are placeholders in an arbitrarily nested structure. It'd be nice to keep the complex HTML in a fixed place somewhere.

Comment: I would just use a simple, lightweight template/data binding library like Knockout.

Comment: This is the problem template engines like knockout, mustache, handlebars,  [various jquery template plugins](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/templates/) et al were invented to solve.  Or you could step up to a full framework like React, Vue, or Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a babel/JSX frontend framework, but you could try something like this:

```
var $new_el = $('<div/>');
```

then add classes and append whatever html into it that you want...

```
$new_el.addClass('thisclass')
$new_el.append( $('<span>a nice little bit of html</span>') );
```

then append or insert it into an element in your DOM (the body in this case)

```
$('body').append($new_el);
```